# Generate 2 columns when using LEFT JOIN on 3 tables

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have 3 tables:

Call table:

```
    +-----------+-------------+
    | CallId    | CallerName  |
    +-----------+-------------+
    | A         | Alice       |
    | B         | Bruno       |    
    | C         | Tina        |   
    | D         | Marina      | 
    | E         | Elena       |        
    +-----------+-------------+
```

AnsweredCall table

```
   +-----------+-------------+
   | CallId    | PhoneNumber |
   +-----------+-------------+
   | A         | 1234567     |
   | B         | 45678       |    
   | C         | 1598        |           
   +-----------+-------------+
```

AllCallsDetail table:

```
+--------+--------+-------+-------------+
| CallId | Caller | Callee| CallType    |
+--------+--------+-------+-------------+
| A      |   1234 |  1111 |        1    |
| B      |   4567 |  2222 |        2    |
| C      |   8927 |    -1 |        2    |
| D      |   4567 |  2562 |        2    |
| E      |   8927 |    -1 |        1    |
+--------+--------+-------+-------------+
```

I have to create a view that contains all recordings from Call table joined with AnsweredCall table (where exist values, where not, display null ) and joined with AllCallsDetails i have to display two colums filtered by CallTypeId.
First column  is like :

```
(SELECT allCalls.Caller Where (allCalls.CallType= 1)) as Caller
```

Second column is like :

```
(SELECT allCalls.Callee Where (allCalls.ConferenceType!= 1 and  allCalls.Callee != '-1')) as Callee
```

Right now i have something like this, but Callee column is always null and i dont understand why, because Caller column contains good values.

```
 Create VIEW [dbo].[CallView]
           as 
        Select      NEWID() As Id
                    ,callTbl.CallId
                    ,callTbl.CallerName
                    ,answeredCallTbl.PhoneNumber
                    ,(SELECT callDetailTbl.Caller Where(callDetailTbl.CallType = 1)) as Caller
                    ,(SELECT callDetailTbl.Callee Where (callDetailTbl.CallType != 1 and  callDetailTbl.Callee != '-1')) as Callee

     FROM [dbo].[Call] as callTbl
     left join [dbo].[AnsweredCall] answeredCallTbl on callTbl.CallId= answeredCallTbl .CallId
     left  join [dbo].[AllCallsDetails] callDetailTbl on callTbl.CallId= callDetailTbl .CallId
```

Output must should look like:

```
+----+--------+------------+-------------+--------+-------+
| Id | CallId | CallerName | PhoneNumber | Caller | Calle |
+----+--------+------------+-------------+--------+-------+
|  1 | A      | Alice      | 1234567     | 1234   | null  |
|  2 | B      | bruno      | 45678       | null   | 2222  |
|  3 | C      | tina       | 1598        | null   | null  |
|  4 | D      | Marina     | null        | null   | 2562  |
|  5 | E      | Elena      | null        | 8927   | null  |
+----+--------+------------+-------------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Kindly post your expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use a `CASE` statement for this like

```
 Create VIEW [dbo].[CallView]
           as 
    Select      NEWID() As Id
                ,callTbl.CallId
                ,callTbl.CallerName
                ,answeredCallTbl.PhoneNumber
                ,case when coalesce(callDetailTbl.CallType, 0) = 1 then callDetailTbl.Caller end as Caller
                ,case when (coalesce(callDetailTbl.CallType,0) != 1 and  coalesce(callDetailTbl.Callee, '') != '-1') then callDetailTbl.Callee end as Callee

 FROM [Call] as callTbl
 left join [AnsweredCall] answeredCallTbl on callTbl.CallId= answeredCallTbl .CallId
 left  join [AllCallsDetail] callDetailTbl on callTbl.CallId= callDetailTbl .CallId
```

See a [Demo Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32d487/5)

Comment: Not working :(. I think the problem is that  when Callee has value -1 i have to  insert null ...

Comment: Not working means? you don't get correct result or what? you can include a else part in case like `when condition then value else null`

Comment: Generated column Callee is null all the time... . I've tried this :        (case when callDetailTbl.CallType != 1 then 
     (case when ((callDetailTbl.Callee != '-1') then callDetailTbl.Callee else null end)) as Callee .. but still no data on this column...

Comment: Oh.. i'm getting an error on the last ')'.. no idea why :-??

Comment: Did you really tried the query. At least make some effort from your end. Anyways see edit in answer and specially the fiddle link with working demo.

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem was that in my real database i have only records where Callee was -1.. Lucky me with your demo. Made me put some question and started investigate in my database.